# Setting up and debugging android installation tracking with facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

We are following this guide on setting up adverts with the Facebook SDK on android.

https://www.facebook-studio.com/fbassets/resource/71/MobileAppInstallAds_ProductSetupGuide.pdf

There is a line in there that tells you to add the following to your app:

```
Facebook fb=new Facebook(appId); 
fb.publishInstall(appContext)
```

However looking through the Facebook SDK code, it appears to send this off automatically when you call authorize (via the autoPublishAsync method).

As we are calling authorize, and it calls through to publishInstall, we have assumed this extra call isn't needed. (Could someone confirm this?)

We have everything working on iOS, which is reporting installs perfectly. However, we aren't seeing as many android installs coming through as we would expect (though we are seeing some - implying it is working to some extent).

While debugging the app, the publishInstall method is called and sends the install to facebook, but the response from that method isn't parsed or validated at all. So presumably it could be failing in production for some reason and we'd never know.

Is there a page somewhere to just view android installs to validate that it is all working correctly on FB's side? Or does anyone have any other suggestions about what might be going wrong, or how to debug this?

Comment: Hello, Some of the api calls referenced in the pdf seem a bit outdated. I recommend you look at this link - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/, and use the latest version of the Android SDK, and use the publishInstallAsync method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Facebook.authorize will transitively also call publishInstall. However, unless you call Facebook.authorize for every user (rather than just when they click on a login button), you may not cover all cases.

You should also update to the new 3.0.1 version of the Android SDK (released last week), which does better response handling/caching for publishInstall requests.

Comment: Thank you Ming! that is the exact problem.